# Get column description after removing a field from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to get field description from SQL Server 2012.

This query is ok

```
SELECT 
    Discription_Table.value
FROM 
    sys.extended_properties as Discription_Table,
    information_schema.COLUMNS as Column_Table
WHERE 
    Column_Table.TABLE_NAME = 'Users'
    AND Column_Table.ORDINAL_POSITION = Discription_Table.minor_id
    AND Column_Table.COLUMN_NAME = 'Login'
```

BUT if one of the columns in table users is removed after making description it is not working any more.

Reason is *ORDINAL_POSITION* is not the *minor_id* anymore.

How I can fix it? Management Studio have to problems with this.

**My solution**: I need to use anther set of tables.

Maybe I am a "habit" and "old school", but for me this solution is more clear and more readable.

```
SELECT extended_properties.value
FROM sys.schemas,sys.tables,sys.columns,sys.extended_properties
WHERE
    schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
    and tables.object_id = columns.object_id
    and tables.object_id = extended_properties.major_id
    AND columns.column_id = extended_properties.minor_id
    And tables.name='Users'
    And columns.name='Access_Key'
```

Thank everyone.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Ok, but if I will use new syntax it will solve my problem?

Comment: This smells like XY: what is the actual requirement here ? get the description of which field from which table ? Can you include sample data, the expected result and the wrong result ?

Comment: Is my question in to clear enough: I need to get field description. How to do it?

Comment: Problem is, what after removing field ORDINAL_POSITION is "reindexing", but minor_id is not. So, value is not the same anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're after `fn_listextendedproperty`

Example: get info for all columns in table `dbo.MyTable`

```
SELECT objtype, objname, name, value FROM 
fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'MyTable', 'column', NULL)
```

<strike>(Going to dig up and add the MSDN link I'm sure is out there somewhere, later)</strike> [MSDN docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853(v=sql.110).aspx)

To only get the data for a specific column, replace the last `NULL` with its name (a non-existant column would end up in an empty resultset, no errors).

Comment: Probably need some correction. SQL saying me "Invalid object name 'fn_listextendedproperties'."

Comment: Had a typo in the query, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query to get extended property for your column:

```
SELECT objtype, objname, name, value 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'schema', '<Schema>', 'table', 'Users', 'column', 'Login')
```

Use schema name of your table